# SQL XML Query/Exist: Looking for null/not null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

SQL Server 2016
Field1 (XML(.), null)

Example data:

```
<ProcessPositionOpening xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.hr-xml.org/3">
    <ApplicationArea xmlns="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9">
        ...
    </ApplicationArea>
    <DataArea>
        <Process xmlns="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9">
            ...
        </Process>
        <PositionOpening>
            <DocumentID />
            <PositionRequester>
                ...
            </PositionRequester>
            <PositionProfile>
                ...
                <PositionFormattedDescription>
                    <ID>...</ID>
                    <Content />
                </PositionFormattedDescription>
                ...
            </PositionProfile>
        </PositionOpening>
    </DataArea>
</ProcessPositionOpening>
```

In this table, Field1 is setup as XML and I have been trying to find all records where the node `Content` may not be NULL. However, I've tried different examples of `query` and `exist`, but can't seem to get the query right. Here is the current one I'm trying, but it's not returning what I expected:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table1
WHERE   Field1.value('(/ProcessPositionOpening/DataArea/PositionOpening/PositionProfile/PositionFormattedDescription/Content)[1]','varchar(50)') <> ''
    AND Message = 'Request Received';
```

I've also tried:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table1
WHERE   Message = 'Request Received'
    AND Field1.exist('/ProcessPositionOpening') = 1;
```

I tried the query above just to see if the basic setup of the query would work. It returns no records. If I remove the `AND` part of the query, I have over 19,000 rows in this table that are all in this format. If I change the `1` to a `0` in the `AND` part of the query, it returns records, but I feel that's wrong as I thought (based on pages explaining the `exist` function, 0 means NOT exist). So, I'm confused.

I want to find all records where the `Content` node has a value, and likewise find all where `Content` does NOT have a value. Any help is truly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Your XML has got namespaces. What makes things worse: There are different **default** namespaces. You can either declare them properly (read about `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`) or you can omit them using wildcards (`/*:root/*:content`)...

Comment: @Shnugo - That appears to have worked. I was trying to work with your answer, but was still not getting any results. Adding in the `*:` to the text worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope the following provides some templates how to solve this:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(Descr VARCHAR(100),theXML XML);
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
 ('<content> exists with value','<root><content>blah</content></root>' )
,('<content> exists without value','<root><content></content></root>' ) --semantically the same as self-closed...
,('<content> exists self-closed','<root><content/></root>' )
,('<content> does not exist','<root></root>' );

--Find a Content with value
SELECT * FROM @mockup
WHERE theXML.exist('/root/content/text()')=1;

--Find a Content with or without value
SELECT * FROM @mockup
WHERE theXML.exist('/root/content')=1;

--Find a Content without value
SELECT * FROM @mockup
WHERE theXML.exist('/root/content[empty(text())]')=1;

--Find rows with no content
SELECT * FROM @mockup
WHERE theXML.exist('/root/content')=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The xml.exist function is not intuitive to me and I've
failed quite often using it. Even though the documentation clearly states how to use it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/exist-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15

But to read the documentation beforehand is not intuitive to me either :)

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(Descr VARCHAR(100),theXML XML);
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
 ('<content> exists with value','<root><content>blah</content></root>' )
,('<content> exists without value','<root><content></content></root>' ) --semantically the same as self-closed...
,('<content> exists self-closed','<root><content/></root>' )
,('<content> does not exist','<root></root>' )
,('XML is null', NULL );
SELECT *, theXML.exist('/root/content') FROM @mockup
```

Gives

```
<content> exists with value <root><content>blah</content></root>    1
<content> exists without value  <root><content /></root>    1
<content> exists self-closed    <root><content /></root>    1
<content> does not exist    <root />    0
XML is null NULL    NULL
```

So I always wrap the condition in ISNULL(..,..)

```
SELECT *, ISNULL(theXML.exist('/root/content'),0) FROM @mockup
```